# jQuery Mobile web app saved to homescreen on windows phone icons

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile

I have a web app with apple icons that works well on ios devices.

A user has added the app to the homescreen of his windows phone. but how to i set the icon/start image.

both big and small accordingly.

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=a280c0590d6c6362&id=A280C0590D6C6362%21834&sff=1&authkey=!AAq6YDSK2FwJu9c

the web app

[redacted]

google search appears fruitless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this on another website that had mobile functionality.

```
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff"/>
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="img/favicon-msapplication-tileimage.png"/>
```